# How do I use Google Apps Script on a single question in Google Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've started doing a Google Form, however I'd like to use G.A.S to do some custom questions, lists, etc. I have found the code to try and I've entered it into the Script Editor, but I don't see how to set the code to specific sections or questions. How do I specify where the code should run?

Answer (score 0):

This will add a short answer question to a form.

```
function addAQuestionToAForm() {
  const form=FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('Phone Number');
}
```

Here's the form:

[image]